# Find $k\in\Bbb{R}$ if the distance from the line $r\equiv\pi_1\cap\pi_2$ at the origin is $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find $k\in\Bbb{R}$ if the distance from the line $r\equiv\pi_1\cap\pi_2$ at the origin is $\sqrt{2}$, where $\pi_1\equiv x+y+z=2$, $\pi_2\equiv x=k$.

---

My work:

$$r\equiv\pi_1\cap\pi_2\equiv\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}&x+y+z=2\\&x=k\end{aligned}\right.\equiv y+z=2-k,\;\vec{n}_r=(0,1,1),\;P_r=(0,2-k,0).$$ Then $\overrightarrow{P_r0}=(0,2-k,0)$. Then: $$\operatorname{dist}(r,0)=\frac{\lVert(0,2-k,0)\times(0,1,1)\rVert}{\lVert(0,1,1)\rVert}=\frac{\lVert(2-k,0,0)\rVert}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}\iff\lvert2-k\rvert=2\iff\boxed{k=0\vee k=4}.$$ My calculations are correct?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think $k=4$ is not a solution (saw in a graph), the distance is greater than $\sqrt{2}$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I guess $n_r$ is the direction of the line at $\pi_1 \cap \pi_2$. But what is $P_r$? Is it supposed to be a point inside the line $r$? If so, it should be $P_r = (k, 2-k, 0)$.

Comment: @Leo your assumption is true and you got the correct result, thank you! Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is correct but you are using a point $P_r$ that does not lie in the line $r$. One correct example is $P_r = (k, 2-k, 0)$.